# Reg Solr Error in Windows 10 Computer,Need steps for Solr Removal from Windows 10 and rerun

Tags: solr, solrj, solr8.4.1

Solr Instance in my Office Lap is erroring out giving out this error logs ;

```
ERROR: Failed to get system information from http://localhost:8983/solr due to: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Parse error : <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/admin/info/system. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:370)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        ... 17 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:370)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

I also started with -f flag , still the errors are coming out. I am really screwed up due to Solr on Windows 10 machine with no reference or no clue on Solr or SolrJ applications with the intention of making one SolrJ client application for User search via Solr Lucene engine.

for this is the third time that I am sorting to Stack Over flow in search of the technical puzzle. if I could follow the logs in Java projects and have debugged apps like in Spring , Spring Boot , Hibernate and other Client Server programming.

Comment: Next time please update your old question instead of posting a new one each time - this error is not the log produced by the `-f` parameter, this is what the web interface responds with. The log that solr produces with `-f` should show you _why_ the core container is not being initialized properly. I've closed your old question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: I happen to take the Solr in Debug Mode , and could find that there is problem in the Configuration , especially in CoreContainer.java in line 700  where in it errors out this line -  containerProperties.putAll(cfg.getSolrProperties()); where in the Conainer Properties are loaded from NodeConfig......I doubt after creating SOLR_HOME in windows environment variables with copy of solr.xml to the Solr directory ....does I have missed some step or misdone some kindly share your noble view .

Comment: I added the reference guide to your other question about references - what is is that you're missing?

Comment: I want Windows Command or REST API for deleting the nodes of Solr and make it standalone with 1 node and 1 collection for I mistakenly created 2 nodes with 2 replicas .

Comment: The collection API allows you to change the layout of your cluster. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/collections-api.html

Comment: I deleted all the Solr Cores and then hard deleted the Solr Folder and then reinstalled Solr Again , Then the new Solr Installation was working fine .Hope This helps